# My ER6 was lowered to accomodate a shorter driver than me. How can I adjust the height?

Tags: motorcycle, suspension, kawasaki, swingarm

I want to adjust the height of my Kawazaki ER6n from 2006. Specifically, I want to reset the height to factory settings. Is this something that's possible to do without hiring a certified mechanic or do I need special tools etc to fix this?

Comment: Do you know *how* it was lowered? Shorter shock, different knuckle? That has a a massive impact on how hard it is for you to undo the change. That said, I would suggest that you have to be very confident that you can do decent work on motorcycle suspension before starting to work on this as a mistake can make you a feature in the scenery much quicker than you'd like.

Comment: It was lowered with the stock suspension still in place. I'm going to leave it with a professional and watch them do it and hopefully learn something useful in the process. It's just not worth the risk since I have no real experience from before.

Comment: The front fork triple clamp could have been lowered (very slightly). Also, the ER6's only have preload adjustment in the rear, so a softer setting would see the bike slightly lower than the hardest setting. There are aftermarket suspension links available for the rear, check if these have been installed on your bike. Additionally, the seat itself could have been replaced/modified with one having lesser padding. Do let us know.

Comment: Thanks for making the post more informative, for the curious: I ended up selling the bike still lowered so never got around to changing the setting!

Answer (score 7):

## Background

There are very simple linkage components that aftermarket companies manufacturer to lower motorcycles. Here is an example of a component sold to lower the Kawasaki ER6.

[image: Link Lowering Kit for Kawasaki ER6]

This is what the shock to swingarm mount looks like with the linkage in place.

[image]

This is the appearance of the shock to swingarm mount point without the linkage in place.

[image]

## Solution

Remove the linkage.  It typically leverages the stock lower shock bolt.  Use the bolt to mount the shock directly to the swingarm.  Use some blue locktight to ensure the two cylinder vibration with the ER6 doesn't slowly back out the bolt.